# CSS Calc works in Chrome but not in Phonegap app on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, css, cordova, webkit, calc

I use the following rule

```
.topbtns
{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:95vh;
 right:0;
 left:0;
 top:calc(95vh - 21vw - 1.2em);
 text-align:center;
}
```

which is used to position a pair of buttons bottom-center of the screen

```
<div class='topbtns'>
<div class='tear t-tosponsor'><div>View Storefront</div></div>
<div class='tear t-continue' id='btnContinue'><div>Continue</div></div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly in my Chrome browser on Windows - even with device emulation turned on.   `$('.topbtns')[0].getBoundingClientRect()` returns

```
{top: 538.2374877929688, right: 375.20001220703125, bottom: 
 538.2374877929688, left: 0, width: 375.20001220703125…}
```

However, when I use the same HTML & CSS and build it into my Android Phonegap app `.topbtns` is nowhere in sight.  The same `getBoundingClientRect` code returns

```
{height:111,width:360,left:0,right:360,bottom:-497.875,top:-60}
```

I thought this might be because

- The Android Webview does not understand `vh` units.  However, I modified the rule to use `bottom:95vh;top:75vh} which worked perfectly.
- I also replaced `calc` with `-webkit-calc` but to no avail.

It is as though `calc` and its `-webkit-calc` cousin does not understand `vh` whilst the webview itself does.

I would be obliged to anyone who might be able to express what is going on here. 
Whilst writing this I have come across this - http://slides.com/html5test/the-android-browser#/.  However, it is not clear to me that the WebView used by Phonegap is the one being discussed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) could help you, the `calc` feature is not supported in some versions of Android (<= 4.4.4), so the problem is not Phonegap / Cordova, is the Device where you test that probably does not supported it

Comment: Good website for bookmark! I used to check on w3school

Comment: I do not think that is quite the issue here - I am not doing divide/multiply operations with calc.  In the end I dropped the CSS and started placing the offending buttons correctly with a spot of jQuery.

Comment: @Sagar - caniuse is a really nice resource.  If you have been using w3schools consider switching to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) as your first port of call when you need a reference for all sorts of web technologies

Comment: @DroidOS I don't get it, was the Android OS Version the problem (<= 4.4.4) to use CSS calc or not ¿?

Comment: I have accepted your answer anyway.  The point I was trying to make - the behavior I saw was not due to the limitations on `calc` mentioned on caniuse for Android < 4.4.4.  In any case I have now dropped the CSS approach here and am using a spot of jQuery instead.

Comment: For my webview the problem is indeed on css calc() on Android 4.4 (tested on a Samsung Galaxy Tab E). The vh and vw units work ok, avoiding calc() solved my issue.

Comment: I see that there are still visitors who look for this information.  A hint: the market share of Android 5- devices is now really tiny. Starting with Android 5 the Webview component shares its code base with Chrome. Starting Android 6 onwards WebView is updateable - every Chrome update also updates Webview (sometimes even prior to your desktop Chrome). Unless you really must support very old versions of Android just consider using Android 6 as your entry level for support. Webview there supports all the same CSS3 as in Chrome.